# WMPLib Console app exception on media play

Tags: c#, console-application, com-interop, wmplib, interopservices

I am not used to using InteropServices but what I am doing is using `WMPLib` to play songs from a console application. ***The application works as expected when I debug it from Visual Studio.*** But it crashes and gives me the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))
   at WMPLib.IWMPPlayer4.get_controls()
   at ConsoleMP3Player.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Ibrahim\Desktop\Console.Mp3\Console.Mp3\Program.cs:line 67
```

When I run it from command line:

```
C:\Users\Ibrahim\Desktop\Console.Mp3\Console.Mp3\bin\Debug>ConsoleMP3Player play
```

Following is the simple code for `play` command:

```
var _player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
_player.URL = "Full path to a mp3 file";
_player.controls.play();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the bad COM control, try using the managed and thread-safe MediaPlayer class instead. Add a reference to PresentationCore and WindowsBase and try this:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

public void PlaySoundAsync(string filename)
{
    // This plays the file asynchronously and returns immediately.
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.MediaEnded += new EventHandler(Mp_MediaEnded);
    mp.Open(new Uri(filename));
    mp.Play();
}

private void Mp_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Close the player once it finished playing. You could also set a flag here or raise another event.
    ((MediaPlayer)sender).Close();
}
```

Comment: I will try it but why will it work from Visual Studio then?

Comment: I will tray to refrain from comments like "it's a bad COM control anyways", and instead tell you that the control probably needs some form reference to work properly, which the VS host may provide? Not really sure, but the managed component is much better anyways.